# Why overloaded operators that are members of classes can only have one parameter

Tags: c++

why cant i used an overloaded operator with 2 arguments as a member of a class like this:

```
myclass& operator+(const otherclass& cl, int value);
```

Comment: Where would `value` come from in `myclass_instance + otherclass_instance`?

Comment: what are you trying to express?  what code would you like to write?

Answer (score 11):

Class functions have an implicit `this` parameter, so a two-argument operator declared in a class would implicitly want to take more arguments than is actually possible: `a + b` where `a` is an instance of class `C` is sugar for `a.operator+(b)`, not `C::operator+(a, b)`. If you just want to keep the declarations of operators in line with the class body, you can declare them as `friend` functions:

```
class C {
public:
    friend C& operator+(const C& a, const C& b);
};
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Given an expression like `a @ b` (where `@` is some binary operator), and the overload being used is a member function, it's treated like: `a.operator@(b)`.

In other words, the left-hand operand of the binary operator is always the object whose member function is invoked. The only other operand it has is the right hand operand, so that's the only one that can be passed as a (normal) parameter.

C++ only has one ternary operator (`?:`) and you can't overload that, so there's no situation in which you could overload an operator as a member function and have it (meaningfully) receive more than one parameter.